# Does ASP.NET use a different .NET framework than desktop?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I Was just reading this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx

It left me a bit confused since the first picture in the article seems to imply that .NET desktop apps and ASP.NET don't share the same framework implementation. I was always under the impression that it was. Any ideas?

Comment: All use the same, they are just duplicating the Framework blue rectangle in the image

Comment: @AmrElgarhy yeah, that's what I though but it isn't really clear especially with the accomodating text.

Answer (score 2):

They use the same .NET framework.

But they don't have to. And this is the way the .NET ecosystem is evolving right now - ways to avoid using the full (ever growing) .NET framework for everything.

As a bonus, the new .NET Framework Core is open-sourced. This is not entirely posssible with the whole .NET framework, since it includes a whole lot of licenses and proprietary technologies.

Given all that, it's now possible to deploy very light-weight web applications using ASP.NET, not even having to use IIS (thanks to OWIN). You only have to include the packages you need - instead of having a single monolithic runtime and BCL, there's hundreds of NuGet packages you choose to use (or not).

Comment: So "Windows desktop" runtime is different from Windows Store, Phone and Silverlight, but is used for ASP.NET?

Comment: "Windows desktop" and ASP.NET were there long before Windows Store, Phone and Silverlight. In fact, if I remember correctly, the portable class libraries ("subsets of .NET framework") started with Silverlight - unless you count things like Compact Framework as a precursor to PCL. The new approach is the "weird" one - in the olden days, you had one framework, and that was *it*. Nowadays, there's many different frameworks, and more importantly, the framework itself is split into many libraries you can choose from.

Comment: Tnx, do you have any more sources to this info?

Comment: Well, the article you linked in your question already has all this information, you just need to read it carefully - it's mentioned in a stride.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to better define "the same framework implementation", as they (full .NET Framework and .NET Core) are built from the same code base with different configuration, and also host your web applications in a slightly different way.

The most important getaway of that article should be "ASP.NET 5 can run on both .NET Framework 4.6 and .NET Core 5". You get different benefits from each runtimes,

- .NET 4.6 gives you best compatibility against previous .NET runtimes.
- .NET Core 5 gives you flexibility on running multiple customized DNX side by side, and portability to Linux and OS X.

Unfortunately Microsoft decides to limit desktop apps to .NET 4.6, but Mono guys have demonstrated possibility to run some (such as WinForms apps) on .NET Core,

https://github.com/akoeplinger/mono-winforms-netcore

Comment: From that post: "The compact framework was a separate code base from the .NET Framework." My definition would be share the same code base and same runtime artifacts.

Comment: @Freek From that viewpoint, .NET Core is completely separate from the "old" .NET Framework - it doesn't have the same code base, and it doesn't have the same runtime artifacts. However, nowadays, you can pick which you want to use, regardless whether you are writing a desktop application or a web application (though with the increased focus on portability for Core, Winforms don't fit all that well).

Comment: @Freek, even .NET CF and Silverlight share most of the code base (and behaviors) with the full .NET Framework. They were just subsets badly tailored in my opinions. .NET Core learns from those mistakes, and allows large application stacks (such as ASP.NET 5) to run on it as well as the full .NET Framework 4.6. You won't get the same kind of portability if sticked to ASP.NET 4.6.